# Alternative to "while" loop

Tags: java

I'm looking for a better alternative to following code. Assume some of the usual programming languages (C/C++, java, ...):

1)

```
while( true ) {
  foo = ... something ugly ...
  if( foo == null ) break;
  ... some code
}
```

not nice because uses a loop for ever and a break that could became "lost" in the middle of some code.

2)

```
foo = ... something ugly ...
while( foo != null ) {
  ... some code
  foo = ... something ugly ...
}
```

not nice because assignment to "foo" is duplicated. Same in this case:

2b)

```
for( foo = ... something ugly ...; 
     foo != null;
     foo = ... something ugly ... ) {
  ... some code
}
```

3)

```
goto INIT:
while( foo != null ) {
  ... some code
  INIT: foo = ... something ugly ...
}
```

"goto" to the middle of one loop.

4)

```
do {
  foo = ... something ugly ...
  if( foo != null ) {
     ... some code 
  }
} while ( foo != null )
```

condition is duplicated.

It seems strange something so common has no good implementation.

Comment: What's wrong with option 4?

Comment: What's wrong with option 1?

Comment: @biziclop: condition "foo != null" must be duplicated. If the condition is something more complex, or is a call to another function, it could be a problem.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui It isn't duplicated because the two conditions are different. One is the condition of processing, the other is the condition of staying in the loop. That the two may be similar in your case is merely a coincidence, logically they are two separate conditions.

Comment: @SLaks: assume the initialization of "foo" needs something more than one line (by example, init a Java PrinterWriter, BufferedStram, is usually done using more than one "new" statement). In this case, the break becames lost in the middle of the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically this is done by:

```
Foo foo;
while ((foo = getSmthUgly()) != null) {
    //...
}
```

Result of assignment operator `=` is just assigned value, so it can also be used in expressions. Whatever ugly just put into separate method.

Comment: True in C/C++, I think not possible in Java.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui absolutely possible.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Why shouldn't this be possible in Java. As long as getSmthUgly isn't too ugly, this might be the best solution.

Comment: ok, it is probably the best, another problem happens when init to "foo" needs more than one statement.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui then you can use a function, like `getSmthUgly()`

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Sasha's solution except I favour a `for` to limit the scope of the variable. An example is when reading lines from a BufferedReader

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)) {
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
        doSomething(line);
    }
    // line is out of scope here.
}
```

Comment: Nice to known the first part of a "for" can be used only to declare a local variable, without init.